# Removing or adding leading 0 in Oracle to match another value

Tags: sql, oracle, leading-zero

I've found many similar questions on this site related to my question, but I can't find an answer to my exact issue.  I'm joining Table A to Table B on control number.  Table A has some control numbers with 6 digits and others with 7.  Table B only has 7.

```
   Table A      Table B
  0000714       0000714
  285073        0285073
```

I've tried doing an ltrim:

```
   select ltrim(control_number, '0000000') as control_number from Table B
```

But this removes the leading 0 regardless of how many digits are in the control number.  A value such as 012345 becomes 12345.

I just need a query that can match the control numbers from both tables.

```
   select a.*, b.*
   from Table A
   inner join Table B
   on a.control_number = b.control_number
```

Comment: Just checking, the datatype is varchar2 right? If so, are all the values in the column guaranteed to be convertible to numbers?

Comment: I can't see the tables as they are in another system.  I was just given the tables and fields to join. I can't tell what any of the datatypes are.

Comment: You can query it but not describe it? Seems odd. Can you create a view over it and describe the view?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server and joining to the Oracle tables via OpenQuery. OpenQuery doesn't allow me to describe the tables.

Comment: Or create a view? Or use `dump()`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you are having issues in casting, You may try extended functionality of TRIM function as -

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
  FROM Table_A
 INNER JOIN Table_B ON TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM a.control_number) = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM b.control_number)
```

Comment: This seems to work.  I've never seen code like this before.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about performance, then you can convert both to numbers:

```
on to_number(a.control_number) = to_number(b.control_number)
```

If you do care about performance, fix your data so the values have the same format.  In addition, declare foreign key relationships between tables where they should be declared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cast()` to convert it integer like below -

```
select a.*, b.*
   from Table A
   inner join Table B
   on cast(a.control_number as int) = cast(b.control_number as int)
```

Comment: when I try "to_number" or cast() as int  I get an "invalid number" error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a **ORA-01722: invalid number** error when trying to cast the column to a number, the issue is probably that you have values in the column that are not numeric.

Using a query like the one below should join the tables as you need.  Depending on your Oracle version, you may also have the VALIDATE_CONVERSION function available to you to help with the joining as well.

```
WITH
    a (control_number)
    AS
        (SELECT '0000714' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '285073' FROM DUAL),
    b (control_number)
    AS
        (SELECT '0000714' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '0285073' FROM DUAL)
SELECT a.*, b.*
  FROM a
       INNER JOIN b
           ON (CASE
                   WHEN LENGTH (a.control_number) < 7 THEN LPAD (a.control_number, 7, '0')
                   ELSE a.control_number
               END =
               b.control_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Left pad the values from table A out to 7 characters using zeros.

```
select a.*, b.*
from Table A
inner join Table B
on lpad(a.control_number,7,'0') = b.control_number;
```

This avoids possible `ORA-01722` errors if the control numbers are not always numeric.

If needed for performance (e.g., if table A is really big and table B is really small), create a function based index on table A using the `lpad` expression from the query.